# Can the verb "insist" be followed by "in"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

> “The third book on the second pile, my dear. Page twenty-three, I believe.
>   You will find a very good picture of a raven. Let me show you how it differs
>   from a rook. The robin will be on page seventy-two, though this time of year
>   the breast will be more sorrel than orange. Now for the Hylocichla guttata
>   pritchardi. The Latin is quite simple. Hylo in a word means wood, and this
>   little thrush is to be found near trees. Gutta refers to drops, or in this case the
>   spots on the bird’s chest. I’m afraid pritchardi is the result of my own vanity.
>   When a new bird is found, it is often named after the person who discovers it,
>   but the Royal Bird Society has refused to accept my bird as a new subspecies,
>   and so they will not give it my name. **They insist that I am mistaken in saying
>   that it does not have the white eye ring**, but I do not make mistakes where
>   birds are concerned.”

Dose the preposition "in" refer to "insist" or refer to "mistaken"?

I myself think "in" refer to "mistaken" and we can also  write it like this: I told them the the bird  does not have the white eye ring but they said I am wrong.

am I right??

I have never seen the verb "insist" followed by "in".

Could you please make the sentence more clear to me if I am wrong?

Source: Listening for Lions by
Gloria Whelan

Comment: You're right.  *In* is not connected to *insist* in this sentence.  The phrases should be grouped something like this: "[they insist that][I am mistaken in][saying that][it does not have the white eye ring]"  Any reason you doubted this?

Answer (score 1):

The verb insist colocates with "on".  It can only be followed by "in" in rare cases, either as an error or when the preposition is not part of a phrase with "insist".

> The shop owner insists, in Hindi, that I have a discount.

(further examples https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-verb/insist-on-upon-in-to/)

Similarly your example uses "that I am mistaken in saying....". and "insist" is being used as speech verb.

Compare:

> He said that I am mistaken in claiming that it does not have a white eye-ring.

The preposition "in"  is not connected to the verb "insist" (or the verb "said" in the comparison)

Comment: Lots of thanks, So can we write it like this:  I told them  the bird does not have the white eye ring but they said I am wrong??

Comment: You should backshift the tense, but that is understandable